# I have enough funds in my account to deploy a smart contract to Mumbai testnet, but Foundry uses less gas than required and my transaction fails,

Tags: foundry

[image]

I need to deploy my chainlink smart contract(which is chain specific) to the mumbai testnet. However the network is busy and more than usual gas is needed to successfully deploy. Foundry however uses less gass and returns a txn failed message, despite my account having sufficient funds. The same script can be used to successfully deploy my contract to Goerli.

Comment: Can you post your script? It looks like you're sending a transaction to deploy, then updating the transaction, and the update is underpriced.

Comment: That error usually means you have a transaction in the pending pool. You need to replace it setting a higher gas price.